# onprocess is not triggering when upload an image

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to upload a image and show the loading percentage in progress

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction(){
            console.dir(event.target.files[0].name);
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
                if(progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentLoaded = Math.round( (
                            progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total );
                }
                console.log("total: " + progressEvent.total + ", loaded: "
                          + progressEvent.loaded + "(" + percentLoaded + "%)");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="myFile" accept="image/*" onchange="myFunction()">
</body>
</html>
```

when i am upload a image "onchange" is getting triggered. but reader.onprogress is not triggered. how to trigger that onprocess event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Event` is `undefined` in the function.So pass the `event` within change function and also insert the file into `reader` function via `readAsDataURL`

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  console.dir(e.target.files[0].name);
  var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]) //insert the file into reader
  reader.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
    if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
      var percentLoaded = Math.round((
        progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total);
    }
    console.log("total: " + progressEvent.total + ", loaded: " +
      progressEvent.loaded + "(" + percentLoaded + "%)");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="myFile" accept="image/*" onchange="myFunction(event)">
```